# Possible values for operands in bitwise-and expression

Tags: c

Given the following C code:

```
int x = atoi(argv[1]);
int y = (x & -x);
if (x==y)
    printf("Wow... they are the same!\n");
```

What values of x will result in "Wow... they are the same!" getting printed?  Why?

Comment: Wild guessing `0`. `-0` is still `0` and `0 & 0` is also `0`.

Comment: Do not conclude that `INT_MIN` also works.  It is undefined behavior with 2's complement.

Answer (score 2):

So. It generally depends, but I can assume, that your architecture represents numbers with sign in U2 format (everything is false if it's not in U2 format). Let's have an example.

We take 3, which representation will be like:

```
0011
```

and -3. which will be:

```
~ 0011
+    1
-------
  1101
```

and we make and

```
  1101
& 0011
------
  0001
```

so:

```
1101 != 0001
```

that's what is happening underhood. You have to find numbers that fit to this pattern. I do not know what kind of numbers fit it upfront. But basing on this you can predict this.

Answer (score 1):

The question is asking about the binary & operator, and 2's compliment arithmetic.

I would look to how numbers are represented in 2's compliment, and what the binary & symbol does.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a 2's compliment representation for negative numbers, the only values for which this is true are positive numbers of the form 2^n where n >= 0, and 0.

When you take the 2's compliment of a number, you flip all bits and then add one.   So the least significant bit will always match.  The next bit won't match unless the prior carried over, and the same for the next bit.

An `int` is typically 32 bits, however I'll use 5 bits in the following examples for simplicity.

For example, 5 is `00101`.  Flipping all bits gives us `11010`, then adding 1 gives us `11011`.  Then `00101 & 11011 = 00001`.  The only bit that matches a set bit is the last one, so 5 doesn't work.

Next we'll try 12, which is `01100`.  Flipping the bits gives us `10011`, then adding 1 gives us `10100`.  Then `01100 & 10100 = 00100`.  Because of the carry-over the third bit is set, however the second bit is not, so 12 doesn't work either.

So the most significant bit which is set won't match unless all lower bits carry over when 1 is added.  This is true only for numbers with one bit set, i.e. powers of 2.

If we now try 8, which is `01000`, flipping the bits gives us `10111` and adding 1 gives us `11000`.  And `01000 & 11000 = 01000`.  In this case, the second bit is set, which is the only bit set in the original number.  So the condition holds.

Negative numbers cannot satisfy this condition because positive numbers have the most significant bit set to 0, while negative numbers have the most significant bit set to 1.  So a bitwise AND of a number and its negative will always have the most significant bit set to 0, meaning this number cannot be negative.

0 is a special case since it is its own negative.  0 & 0 = 0, so it also satisfies this condition.

Another special case is the smallest number you can represent.  In the case of a 5-bit number this is -16, which is represented by `10000`.  Flipping all the bits gives you `01111` and adding 1 gives you `10000`, which is the same number.  On the surface it seems this number also satisfies the condition, however this is an overflow condition and implementations may not handle this case correctly.  See [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement#Most_negative_number) for more details.